# ERROR - "betterdrunkeffect\workshop.xml" - "name" cannot be empty. Я пытался удалять пробелы. Не работает. Помогите мне - горе модеру

Tags: xml

```
<ModMetadata>
<ID>betterdrunkeffect</ID>
<Name>better drunk effect</Name>
<Version>1.0</Version> 
<Description>This mod changes particles of 'drunk' effect on new better animated particle. Try and see what's better.</Description>
<WorkshopImageFile>workshop_preview_image.png</WorkshopImageFile> 
<Overrides> 
    <ModFile>data.lua</ModFile>
   
</Overrides>
<Scripts> 
    <Script>mod_init.lua</Script>
  
</Scripts>
```

Comment: 1. переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык 2. [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Для таких задач лучше использовать XSLT.